# PyQt4 program doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

The program is not working as it is supposed to. It should accept an expression and write it to the textbox above, but it isn't doing so.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Type an expression and press Enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),
                     self.updateUi)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculate")

    def updateUi(self):
        try:
            text = unicode(self.lineedit.text())
            self.browser.append("%s = <b>%s</b>" % (text, eval(text)))
        except:
            self.browser.append("<font color=red>%s is invalid!</font>" % text)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

But I run window appears but when I type an expression and hit return following happens:

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe "F:/Programming solutions/python/pycharmpython/GuiApp/gui1.pyw"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Programming solutions/python/pycharmpython/GuiApp/gui1.pyw", line 24, in updateUi
    text = unicode(self.lineedit.text())
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Programming solutions/python/pycharmpython/GuiApp/gui1.pyw", line 27, in updateUi
    self.browser.append("<font color=red>%s is invalid!</font>" % text)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment
```

please help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the incompatibility between python2 and python3, for example unicode is no longer present in python3. also that there is a bad handling of the exception, for example if the error occurs in the line `text = unicode (self.lineedit.text ())` then the text variable will never have been defined and therefore generates another error in the line that prints the error, considering the above I have implemented the following solution that is compatible with python2 and python3.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Type an expression and press Enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),
                     self.updateUi)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculate")

    def updateUi(self):
        text = str(self.lineedit.text())
        try:
            self.browser.append("%s = <b>%s</b>" % (text, eval(text)))
        except:
            self.browser.append("<font color=red>%s is invalid!</font>" % text)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: awesome...thanks a lot. I actually had thought the same thing but did not know anything about the compatibility of unicode with v.2 and v.3. As for the text thing I was really confused as I did not know anything about pyqt4. this example is from a book by Mark Summerfield. So, if a guy like him had it wrong there is no way a novice like me would know anything.... Thanks a lot ...